# How to work with retrofit in Android when JSON data is dynamic?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, pojo

I am making an app that displays daily stock data to the user. The problem is, I am using retrofit to make the API calls. With this type of JSON, I would need a POJO with every stock symbol. This obviously isn't possible. 
I want to be able to do something along the lines of - `listOfStocks[1].getQuote().getLatestPrice();`

This is the kind of JSON data that I am receiving.

```
{  
   "AAPL":{  
      "quote":{  
         "symbol":"AAPL",
         "companyName":"Apple Inc.",
         "primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select",
         "sector":"Technology",
         "calculationPrice":"close",
         "open":156.21,
         "openTime":1548772200635,
         "close":154.68,
         "closeTime":1548795600703,
         "high":158.13,
         "low":154.11,
         "latestPrice":154.68,
         "latestSource":"Close",
         "latestTime":"January 29, 2019",
         "latestUpdate":1548795600703,
         "latestVolume":39402866,
         "iexRealtimePrice":161.04,
         "iexRealtimeSize":90,
         "iexLastUpdated":1548799005088,
         "delayedPrice":154.68,
         "delayedPriceTime":1548795600703,
         "extendedPrice":160.6,
         "extendedChange":5.92,
         "extendedChangePercent":0.03827,
         "extendedPriceTime":1548799199389,
         "previousClose":156.3,
         "change":-1.62,
         "changePercent":-0.01036,
         "iexMarketPercent":0.02338,
         "iexVolume":921239,
         "avgTotalVolume":42308638,
         "iexBidPrice":0,
         "iexBidSize":0,
         "iexAskPrice":0,
         "iexAskSize":0,
         "marketCap":731605928040,
         "peRatio":13.03,
         "week52High":233.47,
         "week52Low":142,
         "ytdChange":-0.030876717325227843
      }
   },
   "FB":{  
      "quote":{  
         "symbol":"FB",
         "companyName":"Facebook Inc.",
         "primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select",
         "sector":"Technology",
         "calculationPrice":"close",
         "open":148,
         "openTime":1548772200837,
         "close":144.19,
         "closeTime":1548795600692,
         "high":148.1,
         "low":143.43,
         "latestPrice":144.19,
         "latestSource":"Close",
         "latestTime":"January 29, 2019",
         "latestUpdate":1548795600692,
         "latestVolume":17353892,
         "iexRealtimePrice":144.25,
         "iexRealtimeSize":100,
         "iexLastUpdated":1548796485236,
         "delayedPrice":144.19,
         "delayedPriceTime":1548795600692,
         "extendedPrice":145.05,
         "extendedChange":0.86,
         "extendedChangePercent":0.00596,
         "extendedPriceTime":1548799197301,
         "previousClose":147.47,
         "change":-3.28,
         "changePercent":-0.02224,
         "iexMarketPercent":0.02505,
         "iexVolume":434715,
         "avgTotalVolume":25773532,
         "iexBidPrice":0,
         "iexBidSize":0,
         "iexAskPrice":0,
         "iexAskSize":0,
         "marketCap":414371435774,
         "peRatio":19.51,
         "week52High":218.62,
         "week52Low":123.02,
         "ytdChange":0.04048110849056598
      }
   },
   "MSFT":{  
      "quote":{  
         "symbol":"MSFT",
         "companyName":"Microsoft Corporation",
         "primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select",
         "sector":"Technology",
         "calculationPrice":"close",
         "open":104.88,
         "openTime":1548772200862,
         "close":102.94,
         "closeTime":1548795600515,
         "high":104.97,
         "low":102.17,
         "latestPrice":102.94,
         "latestSource":"Close",
         "latestTime":"January 29, 2019",
         "latestUpdate":1548795600515,
         "latestVolume":31105047,
         "iexRealtimePrice":102.895,
         "iexRealtimeSize":100,
         "iexLastUpdated":1548795598662,
         "delayedPrice":102.94,
         "delayedPriceTime":1548795600515,
         "extendedPrice":103.67,
         "extendedChange":0.73,
         "extendedChangePercent":0.00709,
         "extendedPriceTime":1548799195514,
         "previousClose":105.08,
         "change":-2.14,
         "changePercent":-0.02037,
         "iexMarketPercent":0.03309,
         "iexVolume":1029266,
         "avgTotalVolume":40670438,
         "iexBidPrice":0,
         "iexBidSize":0,
         "iexAskPrice":0,
         "iexAskSize":0,
         "marketCap":790189956684,
         "peRatio":26.53,
         "week52High":116.18,
         "week52Low":83.83,
         "ytdChange":-0.002371582278481079
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you explain in detail what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd make a model for `quote` and `symbol` then use a `Map<String, Symbol>`.

Here's an example where the model only has the `latestPrice` property to shorten the example:

```
class Quote {
     @SerializedName("latestPrice")
     private double latestPrice;
     // ...
}

class Symbol {
     @SerializedName("quote")
     private Quote quote;
      //...
}
```

Now making the Retrofit call use `Map<String, Symbol>` should give you a map where you can iterate over the entries and get the latest price of each of them.

Comment: Would I make the call using 'Map<String, Symbol>' or 'List<Map<String, Symbol>>' ?

Comment: `Map<String, Symbol>'` - the json returns an object as the root element. Retrofit can map this to a map of strings to symbols.

Comment: If you could look at it and advise, that would be nice. Here is the link. thanks!
https://github.com/deepanshpahwa/StockApp

Comment: that's pretty much it. Is it not working? One thing I noticed is the `?` at the end of ` @GET("stock/market/batch?")`. That's not needed. I don't know if retrofit assumes that's part of the path or it know it's the start of the query parameters, but I would not put it there. It might actually cause it to fail the call.

Comment: Your answer is right. I wasn't debugging correctly. Thank you!